# Why is my filesystem being mounted read-only in linux?

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, fstab

I am trying to set up a small linux system based on Gentoo on a VirtualBox machine, as a step towards deploying the same system onto a low-spec Single Board Computer. For some reason, my filesystem is being mounted read-only.

In my `/etc/fstab`, I have:

```
/dev/sda1   /         ext3    defaults    0 0
none        /proc     proc    defaults    0 0
none        /sys      sysfs   defaults    0 0
none        /dev/shm  tmpfs   defaults    0 0
```

However, once booted `/proc/mounts` shows

```
rootfs / rootfs  rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext3 ro,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
usbfs /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,devgid=85,devmode=664 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

(the above may contain errors: there's no practical way to copy and paste)

The partition at `/dev/hda1` is clearly being mounted OK, since I can read all the data, but it's not being mounted as described in `fstab`. How might I go about diagnosing / resolving this?

**Edit**: I can remount with `mount -o remount,rw /` and it works as expected, except that `/proc/mounts` reports `/dev/root` mounted at `/` rather than `/dev/sda1` as I'd expect.

If I try to remount with `mount -a` I get

```
mount: none already mounted or /sys busy
mount: according to mtab, sysfs is already mounted on /sys
```

**Edit 2**: I resolved the problem with `mount -a` (the same error was occuring during startup, it turned out) by changing the sysfs and proc lines to

```
proc    /proc   proc   [...]
sysfs   /sys    sysfs  [...]
```

Now `mount -a` doesn't complain, but it doesn't result in a read-write root partition. `mount -o remount /` does cause the root partition to be remounted, however.

Comment: Can you remount the partion rw? mount -o remount,rw /

Comment: Do you use an initrd? If you use one, do you pivot the root file system?

Comment: You say `/dev/sda1` in some spots, `/dev/hda1` in other spots. Mixing the 2 up can cause the issues youre seeing, so make sure everything is referencing the proper device.

Answer (score 5):

perhaps it is because the disk is unclean, try changing:

```
/dev/sda1   /         ext3    defaults    0 0
```

to

```
/dev/sda1   /         ext3    defaults    0 1
```

or at least do an fsck and then reboot

Comment: Even if this isnt the cause, the change should still be made.

Answer (score 2):

You say it's a VirtualBox machine... Does the VirtualBox process have write privileges to the datastore on the host?

`mount -a` remounts everything as described in `/etc/fstab`.  If this is not behaving as expected, there may be some output in syslog.  Check and post here if there is anything relevant.

Comment: I can't seem to find syslog on the machine, I don't know if it's been disabled in the distro I'm adapting, I'll have a look at re-enabling it. There doesn't seem to be any logging in /var/log, presumably because the device is read-only so nothing can be written.

Comment: And yes, on a different VirtualBox guest I can mount the device for writing just fine.

Comment: Oh, right -- /var/log would be read-only.  If only you could edit /etc/syslog.conf you can try logging to a remote host.  But then, if you could do that you wouldn't have a problem.  Have you had any luck since this was originally posted?

Answer (score 1):

If your are running Ubuntu then try first removing ntfs-3g and then install by running 
- "aptitude install ntfs-config"
This usually fixes it. (The problem is that if you installed some other version of ntfs driver (e.g. additional options og parted) then it does not have write capability.)

Comment: I must admit that the post about ntfs-3g didn't look like much to me.. But it was accurate enough to lead me to another solution! I just had this same problem after rebooting a working system. In my case, however, I had to unmerge dosfstols. Best wishes to you all!